# AdjacencyGraph: change edgestyle in combination with KCoreComponent

Tags: graphs-and-networks

For this example I work with the next dataset:

```
 data = {{1, 0.013, 0.113, 0.017, 0.005, 0.006, 0.009, 0.015, 0.012, 
        0.001}, {0.91, 1, 0.113, 0.117, 0.015, 0.106, 0.009, 0.015, 0.012,
         0.001}, {0.19, 0.013, 1, 0.017, 0.45, 0.006, 0.69, 0.015, 0.012, 
        0.001}, {0.29, 0.013, 0.113, 1, 0.005, 0.006, 0.009, 0.015, 0.012,
         0.001}, {0.49, 0.013, 0.113, 0.017, 1, 0.006, 0.009, 0.015, 
        0.012, 0.001}, {0.59, 0.013, 0.113, 0.017, 0.005, 1, 0.009, 0.015,
         0.012, 0.001}, {0.39, 0.013, 0.113, 0.017, 0.005, 0.006, 1, 
        0.015, 0.012, 0.001}, {0.999, 0.013, 0.113, 0.47, 0.55, 0.006, 
        0.009, 1, 0.012, 0.001}, {0.29, 0.013, 0.113, 0.017, 0.005, 0.006,
         0.009, 0.015, 1, 0.001}, {0.09, 0.013, 0.113, 0.017, 0.005, 
        0.006, 0.009, 0.015, 0.012, 1}};

head = {"K1", "K2", "K3", "K4", "K5", "K6", "K7", "K8", "K9", "K10"};
```

I want to create a graph with the thickness of the edges based on the values in the Adjacencymatrix

```
dfMaxtrix[θ_] :=  
 ReplacePart[data, {i_, i_} -> 0] /. {x_ /; x > θ -> 1,    
   x_ /; x <= θ -> 0}
dfMaxtrixg[θ_] :=  
 ReplacePart[   data, {i_, i_} -> 0] /. {x_ /; x > θ -> x,    
   x_ /; x <= θ -> 0}
```

If I work with al edges, the next code will work fine:

```
edgestyle1 = 
  DeleteCases[ArrayRules[SparseArray[dfMaxtrixg[0.0]]], {_, _} -> 0];
edgestyle2 = 
  Table[edgestyle1[[i]] /. {x_, y_} -> (x <-> y), {i, 1, 
    Length[edgestyle1]}];
edgestyle3 = (First@# -> 
      Directive[Thickness[(Last@#)/10], Opacity[.5]]) & /@ edgestyle2;

graph1 = AdjacencyGraph[dfMaxtrix[0.0], 
  VertexLabels -> 
   MapThread[
    Rule, {Range[Length[head]], 
     Style[#, 12, GrayLevel[.1], FontFamily -> "Verdana"] & /@ head}],
   EdgeStyle -> edgestyle3, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Now I want to create a graph with a subset of vertexs. For example only the vertexs when they have a value larger then 0.2. I adjust de 'dfMaxtrixg' using infinity instead of 0

```
dfMaxtrixg[θ_] :=  
 ReplacePart[   
   data, {i_, i_} -> ∞] /. {x_ /; x > θ -> x,    
   x_ /; x <= θ -> ∞}

Subgraph[WeightedAdjacencyGraph[dfMaxtrixg[0.2]], 
 KCoreComponents[WeightedAdjacencyGraph[dfMaxtrixg[0.2]], 2], 
 VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

How can I change the edgestyle-> Thickness based on the values of dfMaxtrixg[0.2]

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to work as posted to reproduce the figure you showed. You don't seem to be handling the `Infinity` values that you introduce on the diagonal and that ultimately get passed to `Thickness`. Also what is `kop`? It is VERY important that you test the code you post in a fresh kernel, to check that it actually works and does what you expect.

Comment: Hi MarcoB. Thanks for your comment. I changed my script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set EdgeStyle after you find a subgraph:

```
g = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[dfMaxtrixg[0.2]]; 
sg = Subgraph[g, KCoreComponents[g, 2], VertexLabels -> "Name"];
estyle = (# -> 
      With[{w = PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight]}, {Arrowheads[w/10],
         Directive[Thickness[w/35], Opacity[.5]]}]) & /@ EdgeList[sg];
Graph[sg, EdgeStyle -> estyle]
```

[image]